# variable in my javascript class is undefined when using an instance of that class

Tags: javascript, object

I have declared this javascript class:

```
var TablixColumns = function(){
this.g = 'wtf';
this.tablixColumns = []; //[];
return {
    addTablixColumn: function(tablixColumn){
        alert(this.g);
         //this.tablixColumns.push(tablixColumn.getTablixColumn());
    }
}
};
```

my problem is that when I try this: `alert(this.g)` the alert comes out undefined
of course my initial function definition read: `this.tablixColumns.push(tablixColumn.getTablixColumn());`

but then I get the error that reads something like "No Method `push` of undefined"

what's weird is I have this class declaration:

```
         var TablixColumn = function(){
            columnWidth = '<Width>3.135cm</Width>'; //default width value

            return{
                setColumnWidth: function(width){
                    this.columnWidth = '<Width>' + width + 'cm</Width>';
                },
                getTablixColumn: function(){
                    return '<TablixColumn>' + this.columnWidth + '</TablixColumn>';
                }
            }
        };
```

and the TablixColumn class works fine, 
and yes, I have declared this.g and this.tablixColumns without the 'this.' part, but it's just refusing to work!
I'm going to kill someone if this doesn't work tonight can someone help me please?

Comment: If you `return` an _Object_ from a constructor, that will be the instance when used with the `new` operator, and therefore anything using `this` in the constructor will be forgotten, and anything using `this` in the _Object_ will reference that object and not variables from the constructor.

Comment: Do you call your constructor function with or without `new`?

Comment: Please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new and http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/11/13/javascript-we-hardly-new-ya/

Comment: @Bergi I called it with `new`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set a reference to the current object (`this`) outside the nested function expression. Here's how your code should look:

```
var TablixColumns = function() {
    ...
    var self = this;

    return {
        addTablixColumn: function(tablixColumn) {
            alert(self.g);
        }
    };
};
```

You can even set a property to the returned object literal if you want:

```
// ...
    return {
        g: 'wtf',
        addTablixColumn: function(tablixColumn) {
        alert(this.g); // 'wtf'
        }
    };
// ...
```

Note that you shouldn't use `TablixColumns` as a constructor if you're returning from it like this. You're using two idioms here; prototypal inheritance and the module pattern. Are you going to instantiate the constructor with `new`? If so, then don't return the object literal. Rather, set the methods on the prototype of the function:

```
var TablixColumns = function() {
    this.g = 'wtf';
    this.tablixColumns = [];
};

TablixColumns.prototype.addTablixColumn = function addTablixColumn() { ... };
TablixColumns.prototype./* ... */

...
```

Otherwise, don't use `this` inside the constructor. Simply make the properties normal variables.

Comment: If he returns an object from the constructor, he should not use the instance `this` at all

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys so I figured out my problem:
all the references to variables of the current instance should not have been preceded by the `this.` keyword
so this is how my declaration looks now:

```
        var TablixColumns = function(){
           g = 'wtf';
           tablixColumns = []; //[];
           return {
               addTablixColumn: function(tablixColumn){
                   alert(g);
                   tablixColumns.push(tablixColumn.getTablixColumn());
               }
           }
        };
```

Thanks @Bergi for pointing this out